# concat strings in array and other arrays

Tags: php

I have three arrays:

```
htext[i], ptext[i], and ytext[i]
```

I was wondering how I can walk through these arrays and concat the strings stored in htext[i] and then take this glued string and concat it with strings in ptext[i], and ytext[i], while separating each string by a space. Right now they get merged without a space between them.

Comment: Do you want to save it on to a different array or a string?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code you have already, then potential answerers can simply correct it as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New to PHP? The variables start with the $ sign. I will assume that your indicate with htext[i] an array called $htext of length "i" (though the solution works with any array, (with numeric indexes, of any length).

You can obtain a single array with [array_merge](http://www.php.net/array-merge) and then join the strings with [implode](http://www.php.net/implode)

```
$yourvar=implode(" ",array_merge($htext,$ptext,$ytext));
```

or, if you have your array exactly into the i-th element of every array

```
$yourvar=implode(" ",array_merge($htext[$i],$ptext[$i],$ytext[$i]));
```

Comment: Hey, I answered similarly and I got two downvotes. Can you look at my answer below and tell me what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @mtahmed: I've just commented your answer on this very topic

Comment: ahhh the $ :p..silly mistake....Thanks :), I was using array_merge only, completely forgot about the implode function

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

e.g.

```
$new_str = implode(" ", $arr1) . " " . implode(" ", $arr2) . " " . implode(" ", $arr3);
```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, maybe  the downvote came when you had just the link to the manual in your answer. Be careful with editing. Usually for me works writing the answer in one shoot or in the opposite order: first the code then, the reference.

Answer (score -1):

Is it what you want?

```
 $new_array = array_map(function($h,$p,$y){
     //any functions
     return $h.' '.$p.' '.$y;
 },$htext,$ptext,$ytext);
```

Requires php5.3

Comment: wrong answer: if you have 3 arrays [a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i] you obtain an array ["a d g","b e h","c f i"] instead of "a b c d e f g h i" string